# Remove Home from menu at module installation

Tags: 8, navigation

I can remove the "Home" tab from the main menu going to `/admin/structure/menu/manage/main`, but I would like to automate it so that it is done at module installation. I checked that the configuration is saved in `core.menu.static_menu_link_overrides.yml`, but I cannot put it in `config/install` since it defines pages created by core. As a matter of fact, I should set `enabled=false` in the already existing `page standard__front_page`; how can I do that at module installation?

Comment: You'll probably need to implement hook_install for your module https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_install/8.6.x

And within there disable the menu item. This might set you on the right path https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204731/programmatically-disabling-menu-item

Comment: Yes, from the link you posted it seems exactly what I need! I'll try it at my next build and confirm that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion from @Leigh Mason and copying almost verbatim from the link he posted, I ended up implementing `hook_install()`:

```
function hook_install() {
  $menu_link_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.menu.link') ;
  $front_page_link = $menu_link_manager->getDefinition('standard.front_page') ;
  $front_page_link['enabled'] = 0 ;
  $menu_link_manager->updateDefinition($menu_id, $front_page_link) ;
  $cache = \Drupal::cache('menu') ;
  $cache->deleteAll() ;
}
```

and the link was successfully deleted. I think that the last two lines are not really needed, I will check it at the next build from scratch...